# Firestore security rule get vs. list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Suppose I'm trying to make a webpage readable only when the user has the exact link to it, could I achieve this using a combination of the document ID and security rules as follows?

eg. I have documents stored at

```
/posts/{postID}
```

I have security rules set up:

```
match /posts/{postID} {
  allow get, write: if true;
  allow list: if false;
}
```

Would simply disabling the "list" operation make it such that you can only access a document if you already know its exact ID? It looks like the case to me but I'm not sure if I'm missing any edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would simply disabling the "list" operation make it such that you can
> only access a document if you already know its exact ID?

Yes, this is right.

Any query to the `posts` collection will return a "Missing or insufficient permissions" error, even a query that queries with the exact ID, like:

```
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('posts')
    .where('__name__', '==', 'exactID')
    .get()
```